# `rake spec` with rails 2 running extemely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am running the following comand on my mac os x shell:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake spec --trace
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:clone_structure (first_time)
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:structure:dump
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:clone_structure
** Execute spec
```

This command stops here for more than 5 minutes before continuing, so I don't know what is happening to cause this big big delay.

Any ideas on how can I find what is slowing down "Execute spec" ?

Thanks